# hashcat has different performance than benchmark results

Tags: gpu, hashcat

I created an g4dn.xlarge instance on AWS,

```
# /hashcat/hashcat.bin -II
hashcat (v6.2.6) starting in backend information mode

CUDA.Version.: 12.2

Backend Device ID #1 (Alias: #2)
  Name...........: Tesla T4
  Processor(s)...: 40
  Clock..........: 1590
  Memory.Total...: 15102 MB
  Memory.Free....: 14999 MB
  Local.Memory...: 64 KB
  PCI.Addr.BDFe..: 0000:00:03.6

OpenCL Info:
============

OpenCL Platform ID #1
  Vendor..: NVIDIA Corporation
  Name....: NVIDIA CUDA
  Version.: OpenCL 3.0 CUDA 12.2.138

  Backend Device ID #2 (Alias: #1)
    Type...........: GPU
    Vendor.ID......: 32
    Vendor.........: NVIDIA Corporation
    Name...........: Tesla T4
    Version........: OpenCL 3.0 CUDA
    Processor(s)...: 40
    Clock..........: 1590
    Memory.Total...: 15102 MB (limited to 3775 MB allocatable in one block)
    Memory.Free....: 14976 MB
    Local.Memory...: 48 KB
    OpenCL.Version.: OpenCL C 1.2
    Driver.Version.: 535.104.12
    PCI.Addr.BDF...: 00:03.6
```

The benchmark result shows hashcat can test 136K hashes per second:

```
# /hashcat/hashcat.bin -m 1800 -b --optimized-kernel-enable
hashcat (v6.2.6) starting in benchmark mode

Benchmarking uses hand-optimized kernel code by default.
You can use it in your cracking session by setting the -O option.
Note: Using optimized kernel code limits the maximum supported password length.
To disable the optimized kernel code in benchmark mode, use the -w option.

nvmlDeviceGetFanSpeed(): Not Supported

CUDA API (CUDA 12.2)
====================
* Device #1: Tesla T4, 14999/15102 MB, 40MCU

OpenCL API (OpenCL 3.0 CUDA 12.2.138) - Platform #1 [NVIDIA Corporation]
========================================================================
* Device #2: Tesla T4, skipped

Benchmark relevant options:
===========================
* --optimized-kernel-enable

--------------------------------------------------------------------
* Hash-Mode 1800 (sha512crypt $6$, SHA512 (Unix)) [Iterations: 5000]
--------------------------------------------------------------------

Speed.#1.........:   136.0 kH/s (47.12ms) @ Accel:2048 Loops:512 Thr:32 Vec:1

Started: Thu Nov 16 01:17:06 2023
Stopped: Thu Nov 16 01:17:17 2023
```

However, when I load 8 hashes to hashcat, the performance is only 46029 hashes per second,

```
# /hashcat/hashcat.bin \
  --status --status-timer 3 \
  -o cracked.txt \
  -m 1800 \
  -a 3 \
  -1 ?l?u?d \
  hashes.txt ?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1

...snip...

Session..........: hashcat
Status...........: Running
Hash.Mode........: 1800 (sha512crypt $6$, SHA512 (Unix))
Hash.Target......: hashes.txt
Time.Started.....: Thu Nov 16 01:47:20 2023 (35 secs)
Time.Estimated...: Tue Jun  2 13:34:21 3226 (1202 years, 199 days)
Kernel.Feature...: Pure Kernel
Guess.Mask.......: ?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1 [8]
Guess.Charset....: -1 ?l?u?d, -2 Undefined, -3 Undefined, -4 Undefined
Guess.Queue......: 1/1 (100.00%)
Speed.#1.........:    46029 H/s (8.87ms) @ Accel:256 Loops:256 Thr:32 Vec:1
Recovered........: 0/8 (0.00%) Digests (total), 0/8 (0.00%) Digests (new), 0/8 (0.00%) Salts
Progress.........: 1630208/1746720844679168 (0.00%)
Rejected.........: 0/1630208 (0.00%)
Restore.Point....: 0/3521614606208 (0.00%)
Restore.Sub.#1...: Salt:3 Amplifier:13-14 Iteration:2048-2304
Candidate.Engine.: Device Generator
Candidates.#1....: karierin -> khshanan
Hardware.Mon.#1..: Temp: 46c Util: 99% Core:1305MHz Mem:5000MHz Bus:8
```

Why is that?

Comment: Maybe read [_Why is my attack so slow?_](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=frequently_asked_questions#why_is_my_attack_so_slow) from the FAQ of hashcat.

Comment: @0x00 It's a different thing, my problem is why the benchmark result and the actual cracking has different performance.

Comment: Which is exactly what the link says. _Note: Benchmarks are a “best case” scenario, i.e. single hash brute force. Real-world speed can vary depending on the number of hashes and attack mode._. And other points too. I don't know in your case why, but they do explain things you shouls consider.